# GRPC: when get a new client?

Tags: go, grpc

I am using grpc in my project, if i have a grpc service call helloService, should i use GetNewHelloServiceClient to get a new client in every function? Or just get once in start program?

```golang
// for example:

c.GET("/hello", SayHello)

func SayHello() {
    c := pb.GetNewHelloServiceClient()
    res, err := c.SayHello(context.Background(), &request)

    if err != nil {
     return
    }
    fmt.print(res.Hello)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a gRPC client just once.

Lots of networking concepts in go are designed for reuse: http clients, http transports, sql.DB connection pools etc. They are all go-routine safe & should only be created once but reused many times.